# What percentage of the time did Bach and others use chord inversions in chorales?

Tags: chord-theory, composition, chord-inversions, functional-harmony, chord-voicings

I know the frequencies of his "Normal Fundamental Harmonic Progressions" i.e., the progression of chord roots. I'd like to know the percentage of time that he used 1st or 2nd inversions in his chorales (where the Bass note is not the root of the chord.) Can anyone answer that?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Don't you want to make a sample yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a study of the subject here: https://www.gmth.de/zeitschrift/artikel/513.aspx
There are also others. Some are used to build Markov chains for music simulation.
Quinn's work referenced supra are a bit detailed. Just looking at major and minor triads, the split is about 63% root position and 32% first inversion and 5% second inversion.